# Access all new Chrome Notifications programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have no previous experience with programming Google Chrome plugins which is why I am starting here to see if what I want to accomplish is possible/reasonable. I do however have a pretty broad experience in programming in general.

What I want:
I want some kind of "trigger" to go off when a new Chrome Notification (you know these little pop ups above the system tray) is popping up. I want to execute some script/code depending on what information the notification contains so that I for example could have an alarm go off if I receive an email from a certain user with a certain key word in the subject and get a pop up from my Gmail Notifier extension. 
This is however just an example and I have a bunch of ideas for different notifications from different extensions and websites so don't get caught up on that particular example.

When I look at the [Chrome Notification API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) I see that there is a getAll method that supposedly is getting all the "notifications in the system" but I do not find any Event for new notifications.
I suppose a possibility would be to poll with getAll a couple of times per second (it needs to be really fast for some implementations I have in mind) but it feels very tacky.

Is there any way to easily access new Notifications programmatically in Chrome?
(I'm open to all solutions, programming languages and such...)

Comment: Is the notification sent by your extension or any other extension?

Comment: As I tried explaining, the Notification that I wish to access can come from any extension or website so: No, it is not from my own extension only. I used Gmail Notifier as an example and I am NOT the creator of that extension, to be perfectly clear...

Comment: There's no built-in "onNotification" method. And I doubt you'll want to make several separately installable companion native code utilities that detect the notifications via Windows/Linux/OSX API and trigger your extension.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have a problem with almost any solution as long as it got the job done (only one platform necessary). I'm only developing tools for personal use so it doesn't matter if it's a little "hacky". But I'm not sure the getAll actually gets all messages that are also created by other extensions/websites than the calling extension. Do you know for sure? (the docs aren't 100% explicit imo)

Comment: You can only access your own notifications.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I searched long and hard and got involved with the Chromium dev group and asked around there. As far as I could figure out there was no reasonable way of accessing all Notifications programatically.

So what I ended up doing was just download the source-code of Chromium and build my own custom version of chromium adding a very crude API. Worked like a charm and not as complicated as one might think.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm interested in pursuing something like this as well, but would rather not have to fork the chrome source.

Have you looked at:

chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function callback)

As per:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications

It would be problematic for any persisting callbacks, but most callbacks seem to be of the 20 sec temp variety, so you'd eventually get the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the same, would you have any pointers on which part of the source code to modify? I'd like to call a rest when some given notification is received.